# How to add app inside application bundle (CrashPlan menu bar.app) to Spotlight index?

Tags: macos, spotlight

The CrashPlan Menu Bar item app, is located as a sub item within the package of the main CrashPlan app: `/Applications/CrashPlan.app/Contents/Resources/CrashPlan menu bar.app`

Applications are indexed by Spotlight, but applications within Application bundles are not on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

How to manually (Terminal) add such an app within an application bundle to the Spotlight index?

Answer (score 2):

I often use Automator to make a stand alone "application" that calls a script or embedded app so that I can place it's icon in the location of my choosing.

There are plenty of other frameworks like Platypus that do similar things.

- http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to copy or move that application out of the parent application bundle.

For example below is the command to copy the "CrashPlan menu bar" item using Terminal.app:

```
$ cp -R "/Applications/CrashPlan.app/Contents/Resources/CrashPlan menu bar.app" "/Applications/CrashPlan menu bar.app"
```